# Running project through Tomcat server

Tags: jsf, tomcat

On running my project through tomcat I am getting an error message like

> Servlet Faces Servlet is not available

Comment: Does your project include the necessary Faces libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865254/servlet-faces-servlet-is-not-available-richfaces-4-tomcat-7) question it might have the answer you're looking for.

Basically, you might need to bundle the JSF implementation with your project.